# Mysterious stackoverflow exception in boost::multiprecision::gmp_float::operator=?

Tags: c++, boost, gmp, mpfr, boost-multiprecision

I am trying to calculate pi for one of my university project using [Ramanujan's](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/ramanujan.html) formula for arbitrary number of digits after the floating point. For the job, I am using `boost::multiprecision` library that is simply wrapper around mpfr and mpir I already have installed on my machine.

So far so good, but I am either missing something or doing something wrong since my calculate function (the one calculating each iteration of the sum in the formula) throws `StackOverflow exception` every now and then. (when it starts it is consistent)

This is how it looks

```cpp
boost::multiprecision::mpf_float calculatePi(int start, int end)
{
    boost::multiprecision::mpf_float partition = 0;
    for (; start < end; ++start)
    {
        boost::multiprecision::mpf_float n = 
            factorial(4 * start) * boost::multiprecision::mpf_float(1103 + 26390 * start);
        boost::multiprecision::mpf_float d = 
            boost::multiprecision::pow(factorial(start), 4) * pow((boost::multiprecision::mpf_float)396, 4 * start); <-- this is where stackoverflow exception is thrown

        partition += (n / d);
    }

    return (2 * boost::multiprecision::sqrt((boost::multiprecision::mpf_float)2) / 9801) * partition;
}
```

I admit I am far too green into whole arbitrary precision calculation/conversions and libraries so I might be missing something.

I can't show you full call stack because it is too long but after

```
ParallelPi.exe!boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>::**do_multiplies**<boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<boost::multiprecision::detail::function,boost::multiprecision::detail::number_kind_floating_pointpow_funct<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0> >,boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>,int,void>,boost::multiprecision::detail::function>(const boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<boost::multiprecision::detail::function,boost::multiprecision::detail::number_kind_floating_pointpow_funct<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0> >,boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>,int,void> & e, const boost::multiprecision::detail::function & __formal) Line 1754    C++
```

Then there are **3603** consequent calls to

```
ParallelPi.exe!boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>::**operator=**<boost::multiprecision::detail::function,boost::multiprecision::detail::number_kind_floating_pointpow_funct<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0> >,boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>,int,void>(const boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<boost::multiprecision::detail::function,boost::multiprecision::detail::number_kind_floating_pointpow_funct<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0> >,boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>,int,void> & e) Line 216  C++
ParallelPi.exe!boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1><boost::multiprecision::detail::function,boost::multiprecision::detail::number_kind_floating_pointpow_funct<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0> >,boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>,int,void>(const boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<boost::multiprecision::detail::function,boost::multiprecision::detail::number_kind_floating_pointpow_funct<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0> >,boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>,1>,int,void> & e, void * __formal) Line 324   C++
```

only to lead into stackoverflow exceptions few calls later in

```
ParallelPi.exe!boost::multiprecision::backends::gmp_float<0>::precision() Line 630  C++
```

Funny as it sounds, I don't recall changing `calculatePi` function before the time it was "working".

Could you guys help me decipher what is going on cause I seem to be lost?

My default precision for `boost::multiprecision::mpf_float` is 150 digits after floating point which previously was not a problem (I recall I calculated some number with 10 000 floating point precision with not SO or whatsoever)

---

### Requests

1.Code of my factorial

```
boost::multiprecision::mpf_float factorial(int n)
{
    boost::multiprecision::mpf_float fact = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        fact *= i;

    return fact;
}
```

Comment: I do not have an answer, but you can greatly improve the performance be reusing some terms. `[(n+1)!]^4 = (n+1)^4 * (n!)^4`, `396^[4(n+1)] = 394^4 * 396^(4n)`. `150!^4` has over 1000digits, `394^(4n)` over 1500. Maybe that will hide the issue.

Comment: I am currently in process in making the dumbest solution work, then proceed with the optimizations, nevertheless, thanks for the suggestion I will keep it in mind when I reach that far. Regarding digits overflow, I did not have this problem before, plus this is happening on the very first iteration of the loop when start is 0.

Comment: @kuskmen: Where is your definition of factorial?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but i suggest you use mpfr_float instead of mpf_float. It also has the advantage that it already provides pi, so you can compare with your result.

Comment: @MarcGlisse changing mpf_float to mpfr_float "fix" the problem and now I don't get SO exception, but I suppose the question remains open why there is SO with mpf_float

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in recent versions of Boost.Multiprecision - I'm trying to figure this out now, but see https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/issues/164.

Note that using mpfr rather than mpf would fix the issue.